# Output path for i18n angular.json

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

i want to add a custom output path for my angular (9) i18n application.
Currently i have:

```
"sourceLocale": "de",
    "locales": {
      "de-AT": {
        "baseHref": "at",
        "translation": "src/locale/messages.de.xlf"
      }
```

And i want that the output is generated in build/at (like the baseHref actually is), but the it is in build/de-AT.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible natively yet but you could use a postbuild script. The related feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16997